# MYSQL get all common tags for images based on a filter

Tags: mysql, tags, unique

I have three tables: image, tag and image_tag_link

- image contains image data and `image_id (pk)`
- tag contains tags and `tag_id (pk)`
- i`mage_tag_link` joins the two with `image_id` and `tag_id (fk)`.

I would like to get all the relevant tags for a given list of tag id's. For example if I have three images which share two tags, amongst others, I would only like to only retrieve those two tags (the ones they all have in common) for a given filter.

I am currently using (simplified to just using the link table):

```
select itl1.tag_id
from image_tag_link itl1 
inner join image_tag_link itl2 on itl2.image_id = itl1.image_id
where itl2.tag_id in (:list_of_tag_ids)
group by itl1.tag_id;
```

However this gives me all the tags for all of the images that meet the filter criteria.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT )` > 2 or 3 whatever you want..

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately it gives me the same result. I've tried with subqueries and various other suggestions for getting items and tags found on stack overflow but the problem here is how to only get the tags that all the images have in common an no more.

Comment: How about first you get the number of images and then do `HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT ) = no_of_images.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution which was related to Manu's answer, indeed you need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ) > no_of_tags` but my issue was to do with the grouping of the images as well as the tags so the final results is:

```
select itl1.tag_id
from image_tag_link itl1
inner join image_tag_link itl2 on itl2.image_id = itl1.image_id
where itl2.tag_id in (:list_of_tags)
group by itl1.tag_id, itl1.image_id
having count(distinct itl2.tag_id) = no_of_tags;
```

Thanks to both Manu and Gordon for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation.  The idea is to get all the images that match the filter.  Then join back to get all the tags on those images.  The following returns the tags in descending order of the count:

```
select itl.tag_id, count(*) as numtags
from image_tag_link itl join
     (select distinct image_id
      from image_tag_link 
      where tag_id in (:list_of_tag_ids)
     ) i
     on itl.image_id = i.image_id
group by itl.tag_id
order by numtags desc;
```

The following goes one step further and returns only the ones on all images:

```
select itl.tag_id, count(*) as numtags
from image_tag_link itl join
     (select distinct image_id
      from image_tag_link 
      where tag_id in (:list_of_tag_ids)
     ) i
     on itl.image_id = i.image_id cross join
     (select count(distinct image_id) as cnt
      from image_tag_link 
      where tag_id in (:list_of_tag_ids)
     ) NumImages
group by itl.tag_id
having numtags = max(NumImages.cnt);
```

Comment: I get an error: unknown column NumImages.cnt in having clause. I tried the aggregation route, I guess what I don't know how to do is get the unique results which you do via a cross join.

Comment: Still no joy, this returns the same tags as the :list_of_tag_ids.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is: I have a list of tags that a user can click on and by selecting a tag it then disables the combination of tags that are not allowed. The user should never have the possibility of selecting tags that bare no results.